# How can i resuse javascript code if it is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, object

I have some code:

```
//The following code is not in a function
var a = do something
b.vr.map.stack = a.stack;

var s = a.stack;
if (s instance of array) {
}else{
}
```

How can i reuse this code in 2 different functions?

```
function 1(dat){
  call the same code from above
  v.load(dat)
}

function 2(hat){
call the same code from above
change dat to hat
v.load(hat)
}
```

1 - how can i reuse the code?

2 - how can i make dat = hat in second function

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to do what you want. Why can't you make it a function?

Comment: Could you just put it in a function?  Then call it in your below functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a function.

```
function vload(hat_or_dat) {
    var a = do something with hat or dat
    b.vr.map.stack = a.stack;

    var s = a.stack;
    if (s instance of array) {
    }else{
    }
    return whatyoudid;
 }

function one(dat){
    // call the same code from above
    var output = vload(dat);
    return output;
}

function two(hat){
    // call the same code from above
    change dat to hat
    var output = vload(hat);
    return output;
}

var one_vload_result = one(mydat);
var two_vload_result = two(myhat);
```